# std::shared_ptr: typedef with custom deleter

Tags: c++, sdl, typedef, shared-ptr

I am using SDL2 to develop a C++ application and want to use `shared_ptr` to hold the pointer stuff. So i do e.g. this:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window> SDLWindowPtr;
```

and i need to use a custom deleter on this whole thing. Is it possible to include this within the typedef? If yes, how? The deleting function is called `SDL_DestroyWindow`. If not, how can i make the `shared_ptr` use `SDL_DestroyWindow` as custom deletion function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Deleter type is not the part of `std::shared_ptr`. You should specify deleter  every time you create an instance of `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: Thank you. The Idea of using a Factory is a very nice idea in the first answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Custom deleter is passed to `shared_ptr` in constructor, so it can't be done using `typedef` (deleter is not part of type of instantiated `shared_ptr`).

It could be done for `unique_ptr` (where deleter is part of type).

My suggestion: create factory method that will produce `SDLWindowPtr` (assigning them proper deleter). Something like `std::make_shared` but dedicated for your system (ex. `createSDLWindow` ?).

Comment: Okay, so it wont be possible using typedef? The Factory is a very good idea! Thanks!

Comment: nope, typedef redefines *types*, you want to redefine *functionality* - use function

Comment: So I'll use the factory. Didnt come to my mind for some reason :). Thanks SO!

Comment: The big problem with a factory in this case is that someone who doesn't know they have to  use it end up creating pointers without the correct deleter. That's a big issue, I think.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you have to pass the deleter on cronstructor of `shared_ptr`, follows an example:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyObj> ptr(CreateMyObj(), std::ptr_fun(FreeMyObj));
```

You could create a factory function to allocate memory for SDLWindowPtr, and other function to free it, if you are working with class, you can call the destructor of the class.